# Javascript convert [[ ]] to []

Tags: javascript

Convert

```
var a = [['12ae11ee12-1bhb222','2019-10-10T19:46.19.632z','a123']]
```

to

```
var a= ['12ae11ee12-1bhb222','2019-10-10T19:46.19.632z','a123']
```

I dont want two square brackets in front and end.

I want output

```
a[2] = 'a123'
```

Comment: so why are they there from the start? Can you change what ever outputs it?

Comment: Do you just want to get `'a123'`? `var b = a[0]; console.log(b[2]);` or simply `console.log(a[0][2])`

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is just assigning the first value to the array:

```js
var a = [['12ae11ee12-1bhb222','2019-10-10T19:46.19.632z','a123']];
a = a[0];
console.log(a);
```

But the right way of dealing it should be making sure that the endpoint or whatever that outputs should output correctly.

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
console.log([['12ae11ee12-1bhb222','2019-10-10T19:46.19.632z','a123']].flat());
```

This solution works if it's extremely nested too:

```js
console.log([
  ['12ae11ee12-1bhb222'],
  ['2019-10-10T19:46.19.632z', 'a123']
].flat());
```

Comment: Why not just `a = a[0]`?

Comment: @lucasvw Answered your question too! Check the edit.

Comment: Yes but that's not what the question asks.

Comment: @lucasvw I updated the answer with other solutions and possible suggestions.

Comment: @lucasvw Wanted to give a solution that's generic... Not something for this case alone... There could be many users coming with similar questions, and while the solution you said might solve this incident, it won't be a good answer. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Thanks but it says TypeError: [["12ae11ee12-1bhb222'',"2019-10-10T19:46.19.632z","a123"]].flat is not a function

Comment: @StackPerson Which browser are you using?